# How do I get smallest postitive integer not present in the array

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I am trying to find out smallest positive number not present in the list `a`

```
def smallitem(a):
    a = sorted(set(a))
    lst = []
    for item in a:
        item + = 1
        if item not in a:
        lst.append(item)
        continue
    mst = []
    for item in lst:
        if item < 1:
            item += 1
            if item not in a:
                mst.append(item)
                continue
    n = 0
    if mst:
        n = min(mst)
    return n or min(lst)
```

I think I have got the solution but it doesnt look correct to me the way I have done it.

for example:

`smallitem([-1, -3]) # 1`

`smallitem([1,3,6,4,1,2, 87]) # 5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the list to a set and then keep incrementing a positive integer from 1 until it is not found in the set:

```
def smallitem(a):
    set_a = set(a)
    i = 1
    while i in set_a:
        i += 1
    return i
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using a set instead of a list?

Comment: The `in` operator for sets has an average time complexity of O(1), as opposed to the `in` operator for lists, which has an average time complexity of O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there's a lighter way do this. 
The time complexity is always O(n).

```
def small_item(a):
    s = set(a)
    for i in range(1, max(s)):
        if i not in s:
            return i
    return max(max(s) + 1, 1)

print small_item([1,3,6,4,1,2, 87])
print small_item([-1, -3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's anther way to do this:

```
def smallitem(l):
    l = list(set(sorted(l)))
    x = l[0]
    for i in l:
        if i != x and x >= 1:return x
        x += 1
    return 1
```

Testing:

```
>>> smallitem([-3, -1])
1
>>> smallitem([1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 87])
5
>>>
```